# Docker and Node - Getting "ELIFECYCLE" when using docker-compose, works with `docker run`

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

This has been driving me crazy for a few hours. I want a docker-compose file that will simply build an image, create a container, and then execute a simple script.

I have recreated the issue as simply as I could

app.js

```
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3");

console.log("DOING NOTHING");
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "example",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "author": "shatnerz",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "sqlite3": "4.0.0"
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:9.11.1-alpine

ADD . /home/example
WORKDIR /home/example
# RUN npm update -g
RUN npm install

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  example:
    build: .
    image: shatnerz/example
    container_name: shatnerz-example
    volumes:
      - .:/home/example
    command: ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

When I attempt to use docker compose I get

```
$ docker-compose up --build
Building example-test
Step 1/5 : FROM node:9.11.1-alpine
 ---> 7af437a39ec2
Step 2/5 : ADD . /home/example
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cbb4467e0651
Step 3/5 : WORKDIR /home/example
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 377b15cc8eab
Step 4/5 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 03be15a4465b
Step 5/5 : CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 286312488783

Successfully built 286312488783
Successfully tagged shatnerz/example:latest
Starting shatnerz-example ... done
Attaching to shatnerz-example
shatnerz-example | 
shatnerz-example | > example@0.1.0 start /home/example
shatnerz-example | > node app.js
shatnerz-example | 
shatnerz-example | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:550
shatnerz-example |     throw err;
shatnerz-example |     ^
shatnerz-example | 
shatnerz-example | Error: Cannot find module 'sqlite3'
shatnerz-example |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
shatnerz-example |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
shatnerz-example |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
shatnerz-example |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
shatnerz-example |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/example/app.js:3:17)
shatnerz-example |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
shatnerz-example |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
shatnerz-example |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
shatnerz-example |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
shatnerz-example |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
shatnerz-example | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
shatnerz-example | npm ERR! errno 1
shatnerz-example | npm ERR! example@0.1.0 start: `node app.js`
shatnerz-example | npm ERR! Exit status 1
shatnerz-example | npm ERR! 
shatnerz-example | npm ERR! Failed at the example@0.1.0 start script.
shatnerz-example | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
shatnerz-example | npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
shatnerz-example | 
shatnerz-example | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
shatnerz-example | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-04-18T06_39_32_565Z-debug.log
shatnerz-example exited with code 1
```

I have tried different versions of node and using an ubuntu image instead of alpine to no avail. I get this error is basically every case, but somehow `docker run shatnerz/example` works as expected.

```
$ docker run shatnerz/example

> example@0.1.0 start /home/example
> node app.js

DOING NOTHING
```

This is incredibly frustrating. I have been staring at this too long. I am no longer making progress. I also updated my docker-compose and docker to the latest versions.

I have `node-modules*` in my `.dockerignore`

edit: interesting, I get a similar error when trying to run app.js from sublime, which leads to to think it may have something to do with the stdin and stdout

Comment: The `node_modules` directory from the container was hidden by the volume mounting from the `docker-compose.yml` file. If you still want that mounting, you need to run `npm install` also on the local machine.

Answer (score 1):

try removing following lines from your docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - .:/home/example
command: ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Since you already add these parameters and required files inside your docker-image.

Just let me know -your output so that I can help you further.

Comment: So that appears to have fixed it. It looks like there is an issue with setting the volumes. Do you have any idea what was actually going on there? Was I inadvertently overwriting the node_modules? I thought I checked for that, but when I dropped to the bash, it was without mounting the volume

Comment: I believe you are missing a / in volumes section. try adding volumes:
  - ./:/home/example              ,,, and no need to add command , as it is already in image

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, I have been able to solve the same error message by running 
`sudo npm install` directly on my computer, followed by `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up --build`